# How to specify build settings for one file?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm working with QT Creator to create an app and I am opening a socket on windows however I do not wish to use the native QT socket and wish to use the one provided by windows. I need to link in a library at compile time using the flag -lws2_32 but I can't seem to find a place where I can add that option in besides the makefile.release. I tried to edit the makefile but it gets overwritten and doesn't compile. Is there a way to specify a build flag for just one particular file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line in project .pro file

```
LIBS += -lws2_32
```

or

```
LIBS += C:/Path/to/ws2_32.lib
```

Reference [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs).